# Input field wide not working properly

Tags: html, css, forms

My target output want same as like blow image.

[image]

My CSS and HTML:

```css
header {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background: #00A6E3;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(44, 62, 88, 0.15);
  display: block;
  z-index: 5;
}
header .todoitem {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  text-indent: 20px;
}
header input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <input type="text" name="todoitem" class="todoitem" placeholder="Enter your activity...">
</header>
```

After write my code input left side showing properly but the right side not showing properly. From my knowledge right side need show 15px padding. But I can't understand what wrong with my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible solutions:

First, you could add `box-sizing: border-box` to your styles. As it is, your `header` is set to match the entire width of its container, and then the padding is applied *outside* that, which is the default behaviour for `box-sizing`, and which makes the padding extend outside the limits of the container.

Some more reading [on css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/).

You also need to adjust the height to allow for the new box model (total height now includes the height of the padding) - here's your updated code:

```css
header {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background: #00A6E3;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(44, 62, 88, 0.15);
  display: block;
  z-index: 5;
}
header .todoitem {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  text-indent: 20px;
}
header input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <input type="text" name="todoitem" class="todoitem" placeholder="Enter your activity...">
</header>
```

Option 2: if you prefer to keep the default box model, you can use a calculated width to compensate for the padding: set the `width` of `header` to `calc(100% - 30px)` (be careful to keep the spaces around the `-` if you choose this option).

Answer (score 1):

This solution is for you.

```css
    
    body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
header{
    height: 40px;
    display:block;
    background: #00A6E3;
    border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
    padding:15px 15px 15px 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(44, 62, 88, 0.15);
    z-index: 5;
}
header .todoitem{
    height: 100%;
   width:100%;
   display:block;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    text-indent: 20px;
   
}
header input::-webkit-input-placeholder{
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<header>
<input type="text" name="todoitem" class="todoitem" placeholder="Enter your activity...">
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this, too.

```css
header {
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
 position:fixed;
  background: #00A6E3;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  padding: 15px;
box-sizing:border-box;
 

}
header .todoitem {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  text-indent: 20px;
}
header input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <input type="text" name="todoitem" class="todoitem" placeholder="Enter your activity...">
</header>
```

I have used `box-sizing:border-box` so p*adding is included in total width*, and increased height of header, accordingly... Main problem was that your padding actually increased width of header - so header width was over 100% (100% + padding).

More about box-sizing: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Answer (score 1):

```css
header {
  height: 40px;
  background: #00A6E3;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(44, 62, 88, 0.15);
  display: block;
  z-index: 5;
}
header .todoitem {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  text-indent: 20px;
}
header input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <input type="text" name="todoitem" class="todoitem" placeholder="Enter your activity...">
</header>
```

```css
header {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background: #00A6E3;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(44, 62, 88, 0.15);
  display: block;
  z-index: 5;
}
header .todoitem {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  text-indent: 20px;
}
header input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <input type="text" name="todoitem" class="todoitem" placeholder="Enter your activity...">
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing float:left, and add text-align:center to header, and text-align:left to .todoitem, then add margin values to .todoitem to position it where you want.

Answer (score 0):

`Width:100%` and `padding:2px;`
doesn't goes well, It never does. Either reduce width to 98% or add padding as `padding :15px 0;`

```
header {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background: #00A6E3;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  padding: 15px 0;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(44, 62, 88, 0.15);
  display: block;
  z-index: 5;
}
```